# Previous file in ubuntu one

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have a huge problem. I accidentally sync broken files to ubuntu one. Is there a way to get previous file (that are not broken) from ubuntu one?

Comment: It won't solve the problem, but Ubuntu One will be closed at the day of 1 June.

Comment: I know that, but I have file that I have to save...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot get previous versions of files, as Ubuntu One file sync does not support file versioning.

If you want previous versions of the file, you will need to grab them from a computer you have, which has them, but which has not synchronized the latest version. There is no other way to restore previous versions of files.

Comment: so there in no way to get those files back. My world just collapsed...

Comment: What if i disconnect it from the internet and I try to recover data? Sent Ubuntu one day back?

Comment: How are you going to recover the data? Where are you going to get it from? If you've already got it somewhere, then you don't have an issue.

Comment: then there is no way of having it back....thanks for your time